# ASP.NET Core, where is FindByID?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application and I'm trying to attach a user to a model:

```
var user = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Model.Author);

var promotion = new Promotion()
{
    Title = Model.Title,
    User = user //error here,
    Created = DateTime.Now
};
```

The problem with this code is that I can't assign `user` to `promotion.User`  as `user` is the result of an async operation. I'd prefer not to use `FindByIdAsync` but for some reason I can't find `FindById`.

Comment: What is _userManager?  Is that your own repo?

Comment: @MarcusHöglund That’s standard ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UserManager` contains only async API and `FindByIdAsync` actually returns `Task<User>` instead of `User`. So you need to make your code async also and use `FindByIdAsync` like this:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Model.Author); // will return the User
```

Only if it is not possible leave your code synchronous, e.g. by calling `Result` property of the `Task` which will cause your thread to block until the result is available

```
var user = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Model.Author).Result;
```

Comment: Please don’t suggest to use `.Result`. ASP.NET Core is fully asynchronous, so there is no reason to suggest blocking on any task result.

Comment: @poke I agree with you. It is a bad practice to use async code in sync mode. That's why I wrote that using `Result` should be considered as last option

Comment: But what happens if you need to do a database lookup based on a users id as an example?  You need the result before you can construct the query

Comment: It looks like you don't understand how `async` and `await` work. Try to read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443%28v=vs.120%29.aspx). `await` allows you to get result  and then consruct the query.